# "Cascading delete" on GAE, NDB, Python app

Tags: python, google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore, app-engine-ndb, non-relational-database

I have a GAE app using NDB datastore and python which assigns tasks to employees. I have Task Entities and Employee Entities which have arrays of Tasks (storing the tasks' keys). I am trying to implement a "cascading delete" where I can pass my delete function the key of the task to delete, and have it "cascade" to employee entities to clean up references to that task. Right now my delete task function works fine but it does not cascade correctly. When I delete a task and check out an employee who has been assigned that task, its key value still shows. I would greatly appreciate any pointers anyone can provide!

My entity definitions are in a db_models file, with Task entities (consisting only of name as a string) and Employee entities which have arrays of tasks:

```
class Employee(ndb.Model):
    name = ndb.StringProperty(required=True)
    title = ndb.StringProperty(required=True)
    tasks = ndb.KeyProperty(repeated=True)

    def to_dict(self):
        d = super(Employee, self).to_dict()
        d['tasks'] = [m.id() for m in d['tasks']]
        return d
```

My delete function, which I am passing the 'did' or the key of the Task entity to delete

```
class TaskDelete(webapp2.RequestHandler):
    def get(self, **kwargs):
        if 'application/json' not in self.request.accept:
            webapp2.abort(406, details="Not Acceptable, API only supports application/json MIME type")
            return
        if 'did' in kwargs:
            entity = ndb.Key(db_models.Task, int(kwargs['did'])).delete()
        q = db_models.Employee.query()
        key = q.fetch(keys_only=True)
        for x in key:
            employee = ndb.Key(db_models.Employee, int(x.id())).get()
            for task in employee.tasks:
                if 'did' == task:
                    task.delete()
                    employee.put()
```

Comment: if tasks is a list of key, I don't understand why you compare it with a string 'did' ?

Comment: Sorry, forgot to add the main.py part where I actually call the thing! Im using curl to test the functions and did is whatever key I am passing in. Im manually keeping track of my task keys right now and passing them in directly. This is from my main,                                         app.router.add(webapp2.Route(r'/task/<did:[0-9]+><:/?>/delete','task.TaskDelete'))

Comment: You are fetching the employees via query, and if this happen shortly after the update, you will find that eventual consistancy could mean you have stale values.  To prove/disprove this fetch the entity that you updated by it's key and see if that is the issue.

Comment: Also even if you are deleting tasks, where do you remove the tasks in Epmployee.tasks  that field also needs to be updated to reflect the task no longer exists.  Just deleting the entity won't affect Employee instances that refer to it.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, you are requesting Employees one at a time and that is very slow.  Instead of:

```
    q = db_models.Employee.query()
    key = q.fetch(keys_only=True)
    for x in key:
        employee = ndb.Key(db_models.Employee, int(x.id())).get()
```

use:

```
    for employee in db_models.Employee.query():
```

Now you simply need to update your employee.tasks property:

```
        for task in employee.tasks:
            if 'did' == task:
                task.delete()
                employee.tasks.remove(task)   # add this line
                employee.put()
                break                         # add this line too
```